# Most efficient way to find path between two given vertices in a tree

Tags: algorithm, tree, graph-theory

I have a tree.
Two vertices a,b are given as input and we need to print the path between them.
One of the way to do it is by find all paths from a and print the path which ends with b.Is there any better solution ?

Comment: Is the tree directed? Is it a binary tree?

Comment: @amit It is just a simple tree .Not directed or binary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let your two nodes be `A, B`.

Simple solution is to treat it as any [Path finding problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem), and ignore the tree property of the graph. In this case, [BFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) or [Bi Directional BFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bidirectional_search) will be much more efficient than finding all paths, and find the shortest path in `O(|V|)`.

In this approach you run BFS from `A`/`B` - or bidirectional BFS from both to get the shortest path.

---

A more complex technique includes treating the tree as rooted, and then you can first find the [Lowest Common Ancestor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lowest_common_ancestor) of `A` and `B` in the tree. Let it be `S`. Then, the shortest path is simply `A->...->S->...->B`.

This can be done in `O(h)` time, where `h` is the tree's height.